# Drawing/Attracting

Tags: word-usage, difference, verbs

Tim completely lost his cool and started yelling at the waitress, drawing/attracting everyone's attention.

Two questions:

1. Are both "drawing" and "attracting" okay in a example like this where Tim doesn't yell to get everyone's attention?
2. Is "drawing" prefered when it's a bad thing that someone gets attention because of, while "attracted" is prefered when it's a good thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a stark difference in the context that you are looking for. Draw and attract in this case are synonymous, but the word '*attract*' is less frequently used in such cases.

Hence I would say,

> Tim completely lost his cool and started yelling at the waitress, drawing everyone's attention.

---

> **draw** - to attract attention or interest [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/draw)

I wouldn't say ***draw*** is used to present only a positive or negative. It can be used in both cases, interchangeably. As can be seen from the sentences given as examples on Google search itself.

> "you really drew the crowds with your playing" (this is viewing a good circumstantial instance) [Source of example](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk03hOYBWOjW3fF-uqmOoBmKwrgKRCQ%3A1603287016315&ei=6DeQX7rlEoD7z7sPjOu1sAI&q=draw%20meaning&oq=draw%20mea&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgCMgoIABDJAxAUEIcCMgIIADIFCAAQsQMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIABBHOgcIABDJAxBDOgcILhCxAxBDOgQIABBDOgcIABCxAxBDUKAOWKkbYM8paABwAngAgAHPAYgBpAaSAQUwLjEuM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQfAAQE&sclient=psy-ab)

> "it was an outrage and we had to draw people's attention to it" (this is viewing a rather aggressive/bad circumstantial instance) [Source of example](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk03hOYBWOjW3fF-uqmOoBmKwrgKRCQ%3A1603287016315&ei=6DeQX7rlEoD7z7sPjOu1sAI&q=draw%20meaning&oq=draw%20mea&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgCMgoIABDJAxAUEIcCMgIIADIFCAAQsQMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIABBHOgcIABDJAxBDOgcILhCxAxBDOgQIABBDOgcIABCxAxBDUKAOWKkbYM8paABwAngAgAHPAYgBpAaSAQUwLjEuM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQfAAQE&sclient=psy-ab)

Now,

> **attract** - to pull or draw someone or something towards them, by the qualities they have, especially good ones/ to cause something to come toward something else, or to cause a person or animal to become interested in someone or something

***Attract*** is more likely to be used and *is used* to view positive instances. For example:

- These flowers are brightly coloured in order to attract butterflies.
- The circus is attracting huge crowds/audiences.
- This movie is going to attract a lot of attention.

---

In general, ***drawing attention*** is more common to ***attracting attention*** in several instances. [Google Ngram for 'draw attention'/'attract attention'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=draw%20attention%2C%20attract%20attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdraw%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattract%20attention%3B%2Cc0)

**Some updates:**
Credit goes to @FumbleFingers. As they said, when you are desperate and wanting attention, it is more likely to use ***draw***. [Google Ngram for 'like to attract attention'/'like to draw attention'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like%20to%20attract%20attention%2Clike%20to%20draw%20attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20to%20attract%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20to%20draw%20attention%3B%2Cc0)

As for negative statements (using not), there are several variations possible depending on the verb you use. However while writing, you can try reading it aloud to figure out which sounds better in the context-of-speech. I have included two such plots, you can try searching for more.

[Google Ngram for 'mustn't attract attention'/'mustn't draw attention'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mustn%27t%20attract%20attention%2Cmustn%27t%20draw%20attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

[Google Ngram for 'doesn't attract attention'/'doesn't draw attention'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doesn%27t%20draw%20attention%2C%20doesn%27t%20attract%20attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20draw%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20attract%20attention%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: A couple of relevant charts - for *negative* contexts, [***mustn't** attract / draw attention*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mustn%27t+attract+attention%2Cmustn%27t+draw+attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmust%20not%20attract%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmust%20not%20draw%20attention%3B%2Cc0) shows both verbs being used about equally often...

Comment: ...but for *positive* contexts, [***like to** attract /draw attention*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+to+attract+attention%2Clike+to+draw+attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20to%20attract%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20to%20draw%20attention%3B%2Cc0) hardly ever occurs with ***attract*** - it's always ***draw*** when it's "wanted".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you for those stats. I understand. Hence I have included the last line. Should I edit my answer to include your suggestion as well, if only you allow me to use that?

Comment: You're always welcome to incorporate any text from any of my comments into your answers. With or without modification or attribution.